# Connection problems with Microsoft NIC teaming

Tags: windows-server-2012, hp, windows-server-2012-r2, network-teaming

I've got three HP servers:

```
DL380G7 running Hyper-V Server 2012  
DL120G6 running Windows Server 2012  
DL120G7 running Windows Server 2012 R2
```

Running various Hyper-V VMs and also running many services on themselves.
All hosts are connected to a D-Link DGS1024D switch, which is in the same cabinet, so the cables (cat6) are no longer than 2 meters.

Both of each hosts' NICs are teamed with Microsoft's NIC Teaming with settings:

```
Teaming mode: Switch Independent  
Load balancing mode: Address Hash (Dynamic on the 2012 R2 machine)  
Standby adapter: None
```

(DL380G7 has 4 NICs, two of them are used for other purposes, so only 2 are connected to the switch in question)

On top of each team adapter is created a Hyper-V switch. All Hyper-V adapters have static IPv4 settings and are on the same network. The gateway router is Cisco RVS4000-r2 connected directly to the D-Link switch.

**The problem is:** while running on one of the adapters in any team (the second NIC is disabled), the machine with the disabled adapter has no problems. Enabling the second adapter leads to delays. Speed is also not affected once the packets start to flow. I've attached screenshots from Firefox network monitor with the second NIC enabled and disabled to see the results.
Screenshots are from the DL120G7 machine running Windows Server 2012 R2.
NICs on it are: 2x HP NC112i 1-port Ethernet Server Adapter

Second NIC Disabled:

[image]

Second NIC Enabled:

[image]

Why is enabling the second adapter in a team causing such a problem (delays)?

Comment: You've made a statement and described your problem but you haven't asked a question. What is your question?

Comment: Edited. The question really is what is causing the delays? Settings, bug, other?

Comment: Did you create the team on the host, or on the guest?

Comment: The team interfaces are created exclusively on the host machines. On top of each team is created a Hyper-V virtual switch and each guest has one virtual network adapter, connected to the switch.